# What can we say about the function which has following kind of Hessian matrix?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have function $f(x,y)$ with $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$. The Hessian matrix of this function has following properties.

1- $f_{xx}>0$

2- Determinant of the Hessian matrix is zero.

Can we say that the function $f(x,y)$ is jointly convex over $(x,y)$ for all of the desired domain?

Comment: you want determinan be zero at all points in domain ?

Comment: @Redshoes I do not want. But actually for $f(x,y)$ the determinant of the Hessian matrix is zero over all the domain.

Comment: @Redshoes I have also clarified in my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
The Hessian of $f$ is semi positive definite every on the domain , because it passes the  [Sylvester's criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/961653/219176)
.

So $f$ is jointly convex on its domain.

Comment: shouldn't we check the (2,2) element according to Sylvester's criterion?

Comment: @LinAlg  you don't have to. even you check it is positive because 

$$f_{yy} = \frac{{f_{xy}}^2 }{f_{xx}}$$