# Check 3x3 or above matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I did read the solution to check 2x2 matrix is positive semidefinite: [Checking if a matrix is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961653/checking-if-a-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite?r=SearchResults)

Is there other method to check 3x3 or NxN matrix is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 0):

Use Sylvester's criterion for Positive-Definite Matrices, and analogous theorem for Positive-Semidefinite Matrices.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion